# Game Maker, Draw Command is drawing infinitely?

Tags: random, draw, game-maker

So I have 20 variables named `fact[x]` where x is from 0 to 19. I have this command under the Left_Released in an object called randomf:

```
if instance_exists(facts) {
with facts {instance_destroy()} 
}
instance_create(x,1395,facts)
```

facts (object) has this code under draw:

```
draw_set_font(FedraS)
draw_set_colour(c_white)
draw_set_halign(fa_center)
draw_text_ext(room_width/2,y,randomf.fact[irandom(19)],48,room_width-32)
```

What is happening is that whenever I'm clicking on the object, it draw a random fact and then deletes it and then draws the next fact endlessly. Where am I going wrong?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I solved it, apparently the Draw function is called every step and not just once. I just used a variable called cast = irandom(19).